# unable to use Face API in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` and `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.Common` to access face API.

But as soon as I am calling a async method i'ts taking me to indefinite task and my page got refreshed.

My development platform is ASP.Net MVC.

```
static Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient faceclient = new Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient(subscriptionKey);

var face = await faceclient.CreatePersonAsync(PersonGroupID, name);

personid = face.PersonId;
```

On executing the `CreatePersonAsync` method the control goes into indefinite state  and page got refreshed

Comment: Maybe you should add details about your implementation if you want some help...

Comment: What's the function where you call `CreatePersonAsync`? Perhaps a `ConfigureAwait(false)` on it can help?